# How to get only rely content (not included quote content) using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to know what to get some content not include quote content.

https://forumd.hkgolden.com/view.aspx?type=BW&message=7219211

The following picture is the example

[image]

I want to get only "唔提冇咩人記得", but I use the following code will get both content.

```
content = driver_blank.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/table[24]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div')
print(content.text)
```

The following code is what I want to capture content:

```
<div class="ContentGrid">
<blockquote><div style="color: #0000A0;"><blockquote><div style="color: #0000A0;">腦魔都俾你地bam咗啦<img data-icons=":~(" src="/faces/cry.gif" alt=":~("></div></blockquote><br>珠。。。。。</div></blockquote><br>唔提冇咩人記得
<br><br><br>
</div>
```

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks~~~

Can `not(starts-with` 's method be solved?

Comment: can you share your url?The image you have posted and html dom you have posted not alike?

Comment: Please post HTML instead of image

Comment: Have you tried wit `#skkHg table div.ContentGrid` CSS?

Comment: https://forumd.hkgolden.com/view.aspx?type=BW&message=7219211

Comment: @supputuri 
I cannot to use it. It is because I have a lot of this CSS. I can use only xpath to crawl different content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below line of code to extract only text node content

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.ContentGrid')
text = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent", element);
print(text)
```

Selenium won't allow you to directly locate an element using text node. Though you can use some JavaScript code to make it happen.

Code Explanation:

`arguments[0].childNodes[3]` indicates 3rd child element of your context node which is `div.ContentGrid`. Please note first 2 child element of the context node are blank (tried with the HTML code shared by you) that's why index **3** used.

Comment: I have another question. If the black text is start to 2nd, 4th, and so on child element, what to detect it?

Comment: For "唔提冇咩人記得", it is work. However, sometimes their reply have more lines. Therefore, I hope to get an answer is starts-with(xxx). Haha. Thank you for your answer. I can reference your method to handle other post reply~~~